# PHP Rest Api multiple paramaters how to send with curl

Tags: php, api, rest

Getting stuck at post to a Rest API with multiple arguments.
I'm trying to change nameservers with an API.

The error i get: `"ObjectInvalid|Nameserver object invalid. Minimum of 2 nameservers is required.".`

I understand the "ns" part is wrong. In the guide i only find this: `"ns"           : [{ns="ns1.domain.com", nsip=""},{ns="ns2.domain.com", nsip=""}],`

This is my code:

```
   $values = array(
      "domain" => "mydomain.com",
      "ns" => "[{ns='ns1.domain.com', nsip=''},{ns='ns2.domain.com', nsip=''}]",
      "contact_id" =>  123456,
      "years" => 1
    );
    
    // Set POST to 1 and send the array with values as a JSON-string
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($values),
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.apiurl.com/api/v1/domains/$domain/update",
    CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_ANY,
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => "username:password"
    ));
```

Comment: That sounds like a question to the API owners? We don't even know what API it is, so it's pretty hard for us to know what or how they expect the data. Have you tried adding the `ns`-string as a PHP array instead? You're already running `json_encode()` of the complete payload anyway.

Comment: You shouldn't build a JSON string manually like this: `"ns" => "[{ns='ns1.domain.com', nsip=''},{ns='ns2.domain.com', nsip=''}]"`. Since you run it through `json_encode($values)` later, that gets double encoded and then most likely cannot be understood by the API. Make it a normal PHP subarray and let `json_encode` do the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly without seeing the documentation, but most probably you should leave the serialization of the nameservers to `json_encode` too:

```php
$values = array(
    "domain" => "mydomain.com",
    "ns" => [
        [
            "ns" => "ns1.domain.com",
            "nsip" => ""
        ],
        [
            "ns" => "ns2.domain.com",
            "nsip" => ""
        ],
    ],
    "contact_id" =>  123456,
    "years" => 1
);
```

Comment: Just one tiny thing - nameservers, not namespaces.

Comment: Yes this is it! Thanks for helping out so fast! (Have to wait untill I can except the answer)